# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when calling Image from Amazon S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, cors, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to export the webpage to PDF and the page has images from our S3 server. When the PDF gets exported the images do not appear in the PDF.

When I inspect the Browser console I see the following errors.

```
Access to image at 'https://skreem2-dev.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/influencers/large-virat-kohli-2retxr.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have updated the S3 Buckets CORS policy to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3001/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any idea how I can render the images into a PDF and bypass this error?

Comment: Make sure the request header includes `Origin`

Comment: @jellycsc should this be done in react? any reference?

Comment: Could you post the react code that loads this image?

Answer (score 1):

I too have gone through the same issue. I have added the attribute crossorigin="anonymous" to the image tag in the HTML page, it fixed my issue when pulling images from the s3 bucket.